# Spring Integration Control Bus message to change selector of a JMS Inbound Channel Adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

I'm currently implementing a flow on a Spring Integration-based (ver. 3.0.1.RELEASE) application that requires to store messages on a JMS queue to be picked up later.
For that, I've been trying to use a Spring Integration JMS Inbound Channel Adapter with a custom selector, and then picking up the message from the queue by changing the JMS selector of the JMSDestinationPollingSource to some matching ID included as a header property.

One of the requirements for this is that I cannot add a new service or a JAVA method, so I've been trying to sort it out using a Control Bus, but keep receiving the same error when I send the message to set the `messageSelector` to something different.

Inbound Channel Adapter definition:

```
<int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter id="inboundAdapter"
                                 channel="inboundChannel"
                                 destinationName="bufferQueue"
                                 connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                 selector="matchingID = 'NO VALUE'">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000"/>
</int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Message:

```
@'inboundAdapter.source'.setMessageSelector("matchingID = 'VALUE'")
```

Error:

```
EvaluationException: The method 'public void org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsDestinationPollingSource.setMessageSelector(java.lang.String)' is not supported by this command processor. If usign the Control Bus, consider adding @ManagedOperation or @ManagedAttribute.
```

Which, AFAIK, means that the `JmsDestinationPollingSource` class is not Control Bus manageable, as it's not passing the ControlBusMethodFilter.

Is this approach nonviable, or is there something I'm missing? Is there any way to set the selector dynamically using SI XML configuration files only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is strange to use Java tool and don't allow to write code on Java...

But that is your choice, or as you said **requirements**.

Change the employer! ;-)

That's correct: Control Bus allows only `@ManagedOperation` and `@ManagedAttribute` method. Since `JmsDestinationPollingSource.setMessageSelector`. We can make it like that. But does it make so much sense if we can reach it a bit different approach?

```
<int:outbound-channel-adapter id="changeSelectorChannel" 
    ref"inboundAdapter.source method="setMessageSelector"/>
```

where a new selector expression should be as a `payload` of the Message to this channel.

Comment: I'm setting the selector using a Transformer over a message that has the matchingID value as a header property and setting the Transformer's expression to `expression="'matchingID = '''+headers[matchingID]+''''"`, but doesn't seem to work. No message is logged, thou, but the message with that header property isn't consumed.

Comment: You have to share that code as an EDIT to your question. Logs on the matter would be useful, too.

Comment: Nevermind. Apparently it worked, but took like 15 minutes to poll the message from the JMS queue. The poll operations shouldn't be every second with the poller configuration posted on the original question? I've marked the answer as correct and upvoted, thanks for the help :)

And yeah, someone was pretty proud that he made a pretty generic app to manage a lot of flows without writing a service and now thinks that adding a JAVA class will ruin his achievement, apparently.